# How to adjust scrollbar with image zoomIN and zoomOUT  in Swing

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to adjust scrollbar when image zoomIN and zoomOUT, My image display on JPanel and JScrollpane contains JPanel.

Comment: How does you (zoomIN/zoomOUT) works, show us a little bit code.

Comment: How do you want it to be adjusted?

Comment: I want to display whole image when image zoomIN with scrollbar, till now only some part of image is display when image in zoomIN.

Comment: please see my Program to understand clearily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For your updated question:

You need to call `setPreferredSize` with your new image size (tested your application with this).

Change in both `zoomIN` and `zoomOut` from:

```
can.setSize(imgSize);
```

To:

```
can.setPreferredSize(imgSize);
```

---

### Example

You need to update the *preferred size* on slider changes. I wrote a small program (code below) that produces this screenshot (with zoom control):

[image: screenshot]

---

**Image Component code:**

```
static class ImageComponent extends JComponent {

    final BufferedImage img;

    public ImageComponent(URL url) throws IOException {
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
        setZoom(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, dim.width, dim.height, this);
    }

    private void setZoom(double zoom) {
        int w = (int) (zoom * img.getWidth());
        int h = (int) (zoom * img.getHeight());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

**Main program:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final URL lenna =
        new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png");

    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 1000, 500);
    final ImageComponent image = new ImageComponent(lenna);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            image.setZoom(2. * slider.getValue() / slider.getMaximum());
        }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(image));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer (`setSize` to `setPrefferredSize` in `zoomIN` and `zoomOUT`). Remember when you call `pack` you change the frame ize and I don't think you want that).

Answer (score 1):

You should adapt the preferred size of the JPanel according to visible image size changes.